# Is it possible to compile a C++ library by android with termux?

Tags: android, c++, compilation, termux

I lost access to the computer. I'm only with the cellphone. Just as android ndk r10e.

Is it possible to compile in android with termux? Are there other possibilities?

Comment: Generally speaking, yes. There is a gcc package for termux, together with a bunch of binutils and friends. Of course, individual circumstances of project being compiled matter.

Comment: Could you give me an example?